# SomeInterface <SomeClass<A, B>> Java - how use this construction correctly?

Tags: java, generics, construction

First of all I have following class:

```
public class Pair <K, V> {
public K key;
public V value;

public Pair (K key, V value){
    this.key = key; this.value = value;
}}
```

and an interface:

```
public interface Generator <T> {
public T next ();}
```

The Class MapData has two parametrs and extends LinkedHashMap.

```
public class MapData <K, V> extends LinkedHashMap <K, V>
```

Class has one counstructor:

```
public MapData (Generator <Pair<K, V>> gen, int size){
    for (int i=0; i!=size; i++){
        Pair <K, V> p = gen.next();
        put (p.key, p.value);
    }}
```

and one method (How I understand this method acts like adapter):

```
public static <K, V> MapData <K, V> map (Generator <Pair<K, V>> gen, int size){
    return new MapData (gen, size);
}
```

So... I'd like to know how to use this construction correctly?
For example:

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    System.out.println(new Pair <String, Integer>(), 10); // Doesn't work at all...
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(String)` takes a single argument.     You should concatenate the two expressions : `System.out.println(new Pair<String, Integer>() +  10)`

Comment: Thanks a  lot, but your answer doesn't work :(. I study Java from the book "Thinking in Java", page 592 - 597.

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
System.out.println(new Pair <String, Integer>(), 10);
```

is not workng because there is no overloaded method `println` taking 2 args...

you mean for sure

```
    String key = "myString";
    int value = 121;
    System.out.println(new Pair<>(key, value));
```

or in old java versions

```
    String key = "myString";
    int value = 121;
    System.out.println(new Pair<String, Integer>(key, value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you wrote the pair class but the first problem is that your print statement isn't declaring a pair properly. You would actually have to send it real values if you don't have a default constructor. Try something like:

```
System.out.println(new Pair <String, Integer>("example", 1));
```

Comment: Thanks! But your answer doesn't work as well :(. I got this code from the book "Thinking in Java", page 592 - 597.

Comment: What do you actually want to have happen? Is my answer not compiling?

Comment: Well, How I undertand,  method map (Generator <Pair<A, B>> pair) shoud to take an argument and then produces an array of random values. This works perfectly if I use something like this: map (Generator <K> genK, Generator <V> gen V, int size)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
System.out.println(map(new Generator<Pair<String, Integer>>() {
    public Pair<String, Integer> next() {
        // generate a new Pair as you see fit, for example
        return new Pair<String, Integer>("foo", 0);
    }
}, 10));
```